# Best practice to set up multiple companies with different accounts and views in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm writing a program using ASP.NET MVC. It's a simple program that will allow dispatchers to track calls and field units' statuses.

Here's where it gets confusing and I'm hoping for some advice on best practice.

The view structure will be the exact same for each company. The page is basically set up this way for every company every time:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
(Header) Company logo - (buttons to filter this company's data you see in the three tables below)
------------------------------------------------------------
New things to be dispatched table
------------------------------------------------------------
New things that have been dispatched
------------------------------------------------------------
Units you've filtered and are checking statuses for in a table.
```

Pretty simple. However, while each company will have the same view structure, the data will be different for each user. For example, in the header, the logo and buttons to filter the three tables will be different for every company.

The tables below the header will have different data for each company.

Also, I want users to be able to access the back end for their company only (add / delete users for just their company, etc.)

It will be set up so I can use the same database and tables for everyone, though.

Here's my question. Would you set up a new view for each company to customize things? For example, you are an employee assigned to company X. If you log in and have that assignment in your table, then you'll load your company's view with customized data and logo. My concern with this is redundancy. The basic code will be the same so if I have to update some global setting, I'll have to do it hundreds of times.

Or do you set up one view with a bunch of if/then statements... like if the employee belongs to company X, set this logo and allow access to this data. if employee belongs to company y, set this other logo and data, etc. The problem with this is hundreds of if then stuff and a very long view.

Any thoughts on best practice for this?

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what I would do in your case and it also depends a bit on the situation, here's why:

If those different companies are different customers of yours which might have different demands regarding the UI, then a separate UI would make sense.

If you are expecting them to demand different logics on the other hand, then maybe a different action might come in handy, too.

If the UI and the logic are expected to stay the same for all of them (which normally on the long run is not the case) then I would store images like the logo and all those things in a company specific folder in your `wwroot` folder, store the company info of a user in a session variable and then load the logo etc. like so: `src="/@Session[companyId]/logo.png"`.

You can load like this also customized javascript (e.g. to render the buttons) and even pass the `companyId` to you ajax functions that load the content of tables etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm planning to have the UI and logics both stay the same for all companies. It's the same job and everything should be universal. But you're right. In the long run with a lot of companies, things may vary a bit. So it may be smart to set up a new UI for all of them. The redundancy gives me a bit of anxiety. I can't imagine trying to apply a global update. Any thoughts on that or am I just going to have to do that the long way if needed? Also, in that case, would you also set up new controllers for those UIs in case of a logic change? The models can be the same I'm sure.

Comment: Honestly, I think storing each company's **specific** frontend in a separate folder is not a bad idea, because you can always create elements from within javascript if some day down the road 1 customer wants to have it different. For example, if today you have a datatable which has same number of columns for all of them and tomorrow you need it to have different number of columns for one, then just create that datatable dynamically through javascript according to the cusomers needs. - Not sure what you mean by global update.

Comment: As far as global goes, let's say we apply an update and want to switch the layout a bit for all clients - maybe switch two tables (not likely but you never know). I'm guessing I'd have to go in and update every single view one by one. Would you also build and assign a new controller to every UI in case there are specific logic needs for each customer or just add any logic changes to the home controller? I appreciate all your help. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: So the main structure of the UI, I'd leave in the razor view. I'd have a `<div id="table1"></div>` in a certain location. Now, when there would be a need to create this table dynamically with JavaScript, you can still always move this div around in you html without updating each and every javascript.

Comment: I also wouldn't rush to make separate controllers since you can always add separate controllers or actions or even just parameters if you create the custom elements dynamically which then can be pointed at the respective controller or action other than the other cusomers' elements.